# Execute a method of class when killing python python script

Tags: python, oop

I am running a python script which interacts with c++ dll and get the value .I want the script to execute **exit_handler** method when we kill the script .I tried importing signals and atexit  but not getting the required event of script getting killed from task manager.

```
from Widget import *
from signal import *

import atexit

class TestMail(Widget):
    startLiveSignal_ASL_0=pyqtSignal(bool)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestMail, self).__init__(parent)
        print("start")

        
    def exit_handler():
        print ('My application is ending!')

    atexit.register(exit_handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = LTApplication(sys.argv);
    ex = TestMail();
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Where am going wrong with this . Am i calling the function at wrong position.